# MSAL callback after login in Blazor app doesn't reroute to return URI after update to .Net 7

Tags: .net, blazor, azure-ad-msal

After I updated my code to .Net 7 the reroute after login goes to the root "/" and not to the requested URL.

We're using Azure Ad and MSAL to verify the user in a Blazor webassembly app. The AD have a return URI to `/authentication/login-callback`.
When a user is unauthorized the user is redirected with:
`NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"authentication/login?returnUrl={Uri.EscapeDataString(Navigation.Uri)}");`

Example:
`https://localhost:44395/authentication/login?returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44395%2Ftest` should return me to `https://localhost:44395/test` but I end up at `https://localhost:44395/`

As I said the problem only surfaces when running .Net 7. When I switch back to .Net 6 it all works properly.

Guess there are something I missed in the release notes. But I haven't been able to find out what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem.

There is actually a breaking change in .NET 7 which causes this issue.

It is described in the [migrate documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/60-70?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#blazor-webassembly-authentication-uses-history-state-for-redirects) together with the fix. It worked for me.